# urllib2 / BeautifulSoup to fetch one page seems slow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm learning how to fetch data from the web. To do so, I'm using python 2.7, urllib2 and BeautifulSoup (using python2.7 because this is the version I'm using at work so don't want to mix-up syntaxes...)

As of now I have a unitary test that is just fetching one page to get some info

Source url: https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/TOR/2019.html

I'm getting team name, year, coach and record for the moment.

I have no experience in fetching web-page but it looks long to me to just fetch one page.

My timings are

```
D:\miniconda3\envs\tes1\python.exe C:/Users/my_name/PycharmProjects/testing/web_scraping/bb_ref/my_test_web_classes.py
urlopen in 1.4240 secs
generate res in 2.8070 secs
Finished get_page in 4.2310 secs
Finished get_team_info in 0.0000 secs
Team: Toronto Raptors   Coach: Nick Nurse   Year: 2018-19   Record: 58-24   
Process finished with exit code 0
```

We can see all the time is spent in getting the information. My test is

```
from web_classes import WebPage
from bb_ref_team import Team


page_bs = WebPage.get_page('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/TOR/2019.html', output='bs')
team_info = Team.get_team_info(page_bs)
team = Team(name=team_info['team'],
            coach=team_info['coach'],
            year=team_info['year'],
            record=team_info['record'])
print team
```

The class getting the page is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib2 import HTTPError
from urllib2 import URLError
from decorators import timer
import time


class WebPage:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    @staticmethod
    @timer
    def get_page(url, output='text'):
        try:
            start_time = time.time()
            html = urlopen(url)
            run_time = time.time() - start_time
            print ' urlopen in {:.4f} secs'.format(run_time)
        except HTTPError as e:
            print e
            return None
        except URLError as e:
            print e
            return None
        else:
            if output == 'text':
                start_time = time.time()
                res = html.read()
                run_time = time.time() - start_time
                print ' generate res in {:.4f} secs'.format(run_time)
                return res
            elif output == 'bs':
                start_time = time.time()
                res = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                run_time = time.time() - start_time
                print ' generate res in {:.4f} secs'.format(run_time)
                return res
```

The class parsing the BeautifulSoup instance to create my Team instance is

```
from bb_ref_data import Data
from decorators import timer
import re


class Team(Data):
    def __init__(self, name, coach, year, record):
        super(Team, self).__init__()
        self.data['year'] = year
        self.data['name'] = name
        self.data['coach'] = coach
        self.data['record'] = record  # win_game-lost_game

    def __str__(self):
        return "Team: %s\tCoach: %s\tYear: %s\tRecord: %s\t" % (self.data['name'],
                                                                self.data['coach'],
                                                                self.data['year'],
                                                                self.data['record'])

    @staticmethod
    @timer
    def get_team_info(page):
        """
        return team page information
        :param page: BeautifulSoup page object
        :return:
        """
        summary = page.find('div', {'data-template': 'Partials/Teams/Summary'})
        title = summary.h1.find_all('span')
        year = title[0].get_text()
        team = title[1].get_text()
        infos = summary.find_all('p')
        rec = re.search(r'(\d+-\d+)', infos[0].get_text()).group()
        coach = re.search(r'Coach: (\w+( \w+)*)', infos[1].get_text()).group(1)
        return {'team': team, 'coach': coach, 'year': year, 'record': rec}
```

Team class inherits from the class below that is just a dictionary

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __copy__(self):
        new = type(self)
        new.data = self.data.copy()
        return new
```

my decorator timer function is:

```
def timer(func):
    """Print the runtime of the decorated function"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()    # 1
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()      # 2
        run_time = end_time - start_time    # 3
        print "Finished {} in {:.4f} secs".format(func.__name__, run_time)
        return value
    return wrapper_timer
```

Does it sound long to you so spend almost 3 sec to generate a BeautifulSoup object, what could I do to speed it up?

Thanks for your inputs

Have a good week-end

**Note**:
I did a small benchmark BeautifulSoup versus lxml and the latter showed better timings.
For each object I ran 100 unitary test (urlopen + generate object representing the webpage)

For BeautifulSoup, I have

```
mean: 2.37027
std: 0.4379433948582853
var: 0.1917944171
```

For lxml, I have

```
mean: 2.27229
std: 0.3342248433315513
var: 0.11170624589999999
```

Comment: What happens in your `Team` class, could you provide that code as well? The HTML source code of the webpage you're requesting looks somewhat quirky, but generally speaking I wouldn't expect beautifulsoup to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I added it in the original post. Thank you

Comment: I tried your code in a jupyter notebook with python 3, but unfortunately I had the same performance issues. Have you tried a [different parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), like [lxml](https://lxml.de/)? And there are some more hints on improving performance in the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#improving-performance)

Comment: I did a small bench BeautifulSoup vers lxml and the latter showed better timings. I put the figures in the original post. I think I'll go for lxml